# Is it possible to use one multi-index query to results with per-index limits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I'm working on a Rails application that is using Elasticsearch to index and search three types of documents, lets call them `A`, `B` and `C`. They are related but its not too important how. There is a search view in which one can search and have items returned under the 3 different categories. At first the set up was to have a list of say the 20 top results across all the categories in one list but that's not working so well now.

Now the view will have 3 different tabs with one for the results from each index, essentially. The current methodology would then break down as I want to have up to 10 results from each category independently and not have say 23 of `A`, 2 of `B` and 5 of `C`, which would happen if I just increased the results limit in hopes of getting a spread. If I were doing this in say Go I'd happily just split this into 3 simpler concurrent requests but I'm hesitant to try this in Ruby as I'm fairly new to it. From my research it seems my options, in order of preference are:

- Have the current Elasticsearch query return up to 30 results, with a limit of 10 from each index (my question)
- Delegate to 3 background `wget` calls on the system and spin later waiting for the results
- Use a multi-thread approach (Ruby processes take too long to start). The prospect of the thread-safety worms that will come out of this can from all the Gems I'm using frightens me.

Number one is absolutely perfect, I just don't know how to accomplish this from going through the docs. I know that you can aggregate results into buckets which sounds close to what I want but is it possible to then also limit the number of results from each index independently?

Comment: you could achieve it in a single round trip using  [msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)  not sure if that is what you are looking for ?

Comment: =) that looks about right. I'm going to play around with that.